# Create a relation without a foreign key

Tags: django

How can I create a *"belongs to"* relationship in Django without creating a foreign key on the DB layer?

Comment: Could just do a `Soft Foreign Key` using a `CharField` and setting the `CharField` to the ID of the "belongs to" relationship.

Comment: Would Django still be able to prefetch & select related models from a CharField?

Comment: Ah okay. I believe Django has a `GenericForeignKey` field.

Comment: @kaan_a the 1st suggestion from Kyvex would not achieve what you want and the second does not apply. See the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually valid.

There is a way for telling Django that you have a "foreign key" in model A pointing to model B, without actually creating that FK on a DB level.

The key is using `db_constraint=False` on the field. This also enables you to write `A.objects.filter(related_b__some_field_on_b=2)` kind of queries.

Here is an example:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    related_b = models.ForeignKey("ModelB",
                                  on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                  db_constraint=False)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    some_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()


big_numbers = ModelA.objects.filter(related_b__some_number__gt=10)
```